# Why operation involving variable does not overflow in C

Tags: c

I have a code that's something like this in C:

```
int main(){
   unsigned char var1;

   var1 = 255;
   var1 = var1 + 1;

   printf("The result is = %i", var1);

}
```

I think that it will overflow since max type for var1 is up to 255 so when you increment it to 1, it will be 256 but the result is 0.

But when I modified the code something like this:

```
int main(){
   unsigned char var1;

   var1 = 255+ 1;

   printf("The result is = %i", var1);

}
```

The result gives an overflow error like "warning: unsigned conversion from 'int' to 'unsigned char' changes value from '256' to '0' [-Woverflow]".

Why is that the 1st code does not overflow?

Comment: If it prints 0 then the first example *did* overflow. That's what happens when an unsigned integral variable overflows: it wraps around to 0. Are you asking why there's no compiler warning? The answer to that is straightforward: the overflow isn't at compile-time, it's at run-time. (And anyways, run-time overflow is well-defined and often intentional. It's not a bug. Compile-time overflow usually is.)

Comment: Both of the codes have the same effect, the compiler is not being very accurate in deciding when to show the warning.

Comment: Detail: There is **no overflow** here.  Both `var1 + 1` and `255+ 1` do not overflow.  `int` overflow is UB.  Instead is a _conversion_ from from `int` to `unsigned char`.  That is well defined.  Integer overflow has some similarities to conversion issues, yet C specifies them differently.

Comment: @chux AFAIK, `unsigned` (which the OP uses) overflow is well defined in C. Agree, of course, that we have no overflow here, but could introduce it by `var1 = var1 + (unsigned char)1;`.

Comment: @GermanNerd `var1 + (unsigned char)1` cannot overflow when `var1` is an 8-bit `unsigned char`. Prior to the addition, both are go thought the _usual arithmetic conversions_ and become `int`, which is at least 16-bit.  The sum is then in range: no overflow.  Should the sum exceed 255, the _assignment_ to a `unsigned char` causes a reduction, but agin, that is not _overflow_ in C.

Comment: @chux Funny, for decades I had it in my mind that integer promotions were only ever done when integer types did not match...Has the current behaviour always been so in C? And thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @GermanNerd In most cases, operands ranking less than `int/unsigned` go through  the _usual arithmetic conversions_ (and then conversions may happen when types do not match).  I am confident that is since C89.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why that decision was taken; it seems inconsistent to me. And what about `unsigned char a_byte = 255; a_byte++;` ?  Is that overflow?

Comment: @GermanNerd "decision was taken" to simplify the possibilities of type of operations as `int/unsigned` is the preferred size.

Answer (score 5):

Wraparound for unsigned char (essentially a byte) is by design.

Your second example, however, is adding two ints.  Converting from 256 in an int to zero in a byte constitutes loss of information; hence the warning.

Comment: The first case also converts the `int` value `256` to a byte  (integer promotion applies to the operands in `var1 + 1`)

Comment: Then perhaps the warning is by virtue of the fact that the compiler can tell at compile-time that loss of precision will occur in the second example.  Wraparound for bytes is still by design, and does not cause an error at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is that the 1st code does not overflow?

The first code overflows exactly as much as the second one does, and in exactly the same place: the assignment of the sum to variable `var1`.

In the first example, the initial value of unsigned char `var1`, 255, is converted to type `int` and 1 is added to it.  The resulting `int` value 256 is then converted to type `unsigned char`, which by definition involves reducing it modulo 256,<sup>*</sup> yielding 0.  The second example is exactly the same, except that the left operand is already the `int` 255, not requiring conversion.  Exactly the same sum is computed, and exactly the same conversion to `unsigned char` is performed.  There is exactly as much overflow in one case as in the other.

The difference is simply in what your particular compiler thinks appropriate to warn about.  It is in no way obligated to produce any warnings here at all, and it chooses, at its own discretion, that the second version should elicit a warning, but the first one should not.

Perhaps it thinks that the second one is relatively more likely to constitute a programming error than the first (plausible), and that the appropriate threshold for a warning lies between (debatable).  Or perhaps, as @RobertHarvey suggested in comments, it does not analyze the code deeply enough to recognize that the expression `var1 + 1` definitely overflows in this case.

---

<sup>*</sup> More generally, the conversion involves reducing the result modulo one more than the maximum representable value of result type, `unsigned char`.  You have 8-bit `unsigned char`s, which is very normal.  Their range is 0 - 255, so the reduction is modulo 256.  Similar applies to conversions to all other unsigned integer types, and to arithmetic on unsigned types where that is actually done.

Comment: Detail: [no overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54413352/why-operation-involving-variable-does-not-overflow-in-c#comment95638949_54413352).  OP is experience conversion issues.

Comment: @chux, I guess that's a question of terminology.  I use the OP's (and GCC's) definition of "overflow" in this answer, which, I agree, differs from the standard's.

Comment: John, disappointedly, I failed to find good info on definition of "-Woverflow" with modern gcc.